# Cane and metric_fu like code metrics for CoffeeScript?

Tags: automation, coffeescript, code-metrics

Rails has a lot of easy to use code metric tools like metric_fu, cane etc.

Are there any similar tools for CoffeeScript?

So far I've found [CoffeeLint](http://www.coffeelint.org/), which checks for correct coding style. But its feature set is limited to syntax checks.